# Implications of Calling static Angular service methods from class getter

Tags: angular, typescript

I guess I'm asking if I'm making my classes **too smart**.

SomeService

```js
public static getThings(owner:Owner):Thing[]{
    return someInjectedDBService.getThingsForOwner(owner);
}
```

OwnerClass

```js
import { SomeService } from './services/some.service';
export class Owner {
    getThings():Thing[]{
        return SomeService.getThings(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have a problem with that approach. So far I know you can not call `someInjectedDBService` if it's not declared `static` also. 
But you have to try to use that approach in a real example, and see if you can declare `getThings` in `SomeService` as `static` without getting an error.

Comment: Apart from what @Sheki mentioned, If you intend to unit test your code, then it will not be easy to mock.